# Hook to add a new column in control panel

Tags: control-panel, add-on-development, extension

For an extension I would like to add an extra column in the cp's entries overview. I have searched for a hook I could use for this, but could not find anything.

I could use Zenbu, but that is a bit too much for what I want. In EE1 there was a hook available. Have I missed the hook for EE2 or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with the hook cp_js_end. I linked it with this function:

```
function addJs(){
        $js = "
             if(window.location.href.indexOf('content_edit') > -1) 
             {
                var colNr = 2;  

                $('.mainTable').find('tr').each(function(){
                    $(this).find('th').eq(colNr).after('<th data-table_column=\'your-colomn-name\'>Your column name</th>');
                    $(this).find('td').eq(colNr).after('<td>Your content for this cell</td>');
               });
            }
        ";

        return $this->EE->extensions->last_call . $js;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Which page, specifically? Have you looked at the **tab** documentation?

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/modules.html#the-tab-file-tab-module-name-php

Expand on your answer I can probably help you.

Comment: The content_edit page. I haven't tought of looking at the tab documentation. I will look later into that.